# Android maven plugin to generate multiple dex files

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

How can I use android maven plugin to generate multiple dex files instead one to avoid the android 64k method problem? Is possible to do that using this plugin or I have to use gradle to do that?

Solution: With this pull request https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin/pull/482 the plugin will be able to create android applications that will work ok with the new Android Multidex Support Library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen in the change log of the android-maven-plugin version 4.0.0-rc.1 support multi-dex.
See https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Changelog
Also in the source https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jayway/maven/plugins/android/phase08preparepackage/DexMojo.java are multi-dex suport.
But I have not seen how to configure dex in the pom.xml file (no docu jet).
Maybe this help https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/maven-android-developers/Ren55dpnzsw

Comment: You can configure the dex inside the tag configuration. It works, and when this pull request  https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin/pull/482 will be included in the next plugin version, the problem will be solved.